# Using "transform" and a struct in cython to implement operations on vectors

Tags: python, matrix, vector, struct, cython

I have been trying to write a `Matrix class` which used a one dimensional `vector` in order to build up a two-dimensional matrix. My main goal is to be able to add row or column to my Matrix, using this class, in addition of being able to do normal matrix operations. My current issue is how to **add/subtract/multiply** element by element of two matrices? I'd like to use vector properties in order to solve this problem by applying the idea of [this answer](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/20431-stl-element-wise-addition-contents-two-containers.html). But so far I wasn't successful. How can I use transform and plus/minus for element-wise two vectors operations??

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import cython
import numpy as np
import ctypes
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython                                               

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std" nogil:    
     OutputIter copy[InputIter,OutputIter](InputIter,InputIter,OutputIter)
     #http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform
     OutputIter transform[InputIter, OutputIter, UnaryOperation]( InputIter,InputIter,OutputIter, UnaryOperation )


cdef struct plus:
    T operator[] (T& x, T& y): 
      return x+y
cdef class Matrix:
     cdef vector[double] matrix   
     cdef int _rows
     cdef int _columns

     def __cinit__(self, int rows=0, int columns=0, bint Identity=False):
         self._rows=rows
         self._columns=columns
         self.matrix.resize(rows*columns)
         if Identity:
            self._IdentityMatrix()

     property rows:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._rows
        def __set__(self, int x):
            self._rows = x    
     property columns:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._columns
        def __set__(self, int y):
            self._columns = y    


     cpdef double getVal(self, int r, int c):
           return self.matrix[r*self._columns+c]

     cpdef void setVal(self, int r, int c, double v): 
           self.matrix[r*self._columns+c] = v

     cpdef void AddRow(self, vector[double] row):
           cdef int i
           if (row.size()!=self._columns):
              raise Exception('The size of appended row is wrong!')
           else:
              self._rows+=1
              for i from 0 <= i <self._columns:
                  self.matrix.push_back(row[i])

     cpdef void AddColumn(self, vector[double] col):
           cdef int i
           if (col.size()!=self._rows):
              raise Exception('The size of appended column is wrong!')

           else:

              for i from 0 <= i <self._rows:
                  self.matrix.insert(self.matrix.begin()+i+(i+1)*self._columns, col[i])

              self._columns+=1 
     cpdef Matrix transpose(self):
           cdef int i,j 
           cdef Matrix m = Matrix(self._columns,self._rows)
           for i from 0 <= i <self._columns:
               for j from 0 <= j <self._rows:
                   m.setVal(i,j,self.getVal(j,i))
           return m

     cdef void _IdentityMatrix(self):
          cdef int i 
          if (self._rows!=self._columns):
             raise Exception('In order to generate identity matrix, the number of rows and columns must be equal')
          else:
             for i from 0 <= i <self._columns:
                 self.setVal(i,i,1.0)

     cpdef void add(self, Matrix m):
           if ((self._rows!=m._rows) or (self._columns!=m._columns)):
              raise Exception('In order to add two matrices, they must have equal number of rows and columns')
           else:
              transform(self.begin( ), m.begin( ), self.begin( ),plus())
```

I will appreciate if I get answer to solve just this problem.

Comment: A quick pointer: I think `plus` should have `operator()` rather than `operator[]`. It's also probably easier to define it for `double` rather than trying to make a template function.

Comment: @DaivdW How should it be done? I changed it to `cdef struct plus:
     double operator() (double x, double y): 
       return x+y` and got this error:`double operator() (double x, double y): 
                                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

matrix.pyx:16:43: C function definition not allowed here`

Comment: @DavidW Well, how about using `plus` from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus)? How should I get the header from c++ library? Thanks again :)

Comment: Try changing `cdef struct plus` to `cdef cppclass plus` to define it in Cython (I'm not able to test it currently though). Don't know about getting it from the standard library right now.

Comment: @DavidW I got more error messages:`double operator() (double x, double y): 
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

matrix.pyx:16:24: Compiler crash in ControlFlowAnalysis

ModuleNode.body = StatListNode(matrix.pyx:1:0)
CppClassNode.attributes[0] = CFuncDefNode(matrix.pyx:16:5,
    args = [...]/2,
    modifiers = [...]/0,
    visibility = u'private')
Compiler crash traceback from this point on:`

Comment: I don't know then, sorry

Comment: One last thought - I think I've made something similar work by using a different function name for Cython and giving the real name in quotes after: e.g. `double plus_func(double x, double y) "operator()":`. If that doesn't work I _really_ don't know though.

Comment: @DavidW I did the following to wrap the `plus` from `functional`:  `cdef extern from "<functional>" namespace "std" nogil:
     cdef cppclass plus[T]:
          T operator[]( T& , T& )` and getting the following error, when I compile my code:`‘T’ was not declared in this scope
     __pyx_t_5 = std::transform<PyObject *,PyObject *,std::plus<T> >(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3,
                                                                ^`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Pass `plus[double]()` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big part of your problem is that you've misunderstood the documentation for the C++ transform function and are calling the "UnaryOperation" variant of it (where the function takes only one argument).

Instead you need to call the "BinaryOperation" version. Note that for the container range needs a begin and end iterator (the second input and output are assumed to be of equal length).

Here's a minimal working example:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":    
     #http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform
     OutputIter transform[InputIter1, InputIter2, OutputIter, BinaryOperation]( InputIter1,InputIter1,InputIter2,OutputIter, BinaryOperation)

cdef extern from "<functional>" namespace "std":
     cdef cppclass plus[T]:
         plus()

def example():
    cdef vector[double] v1=[1,2,3]
    cdef vector[double] v2=[2,3,4]

    transform(v1.begin(),v1.end(), 
              v2.begin(),
              v1.begin(),
              plus[double]())

    print(v1)
```

---

A small detail of your code that I noticed is that you allow assignment to the `rows` and `columns` properties. This is a bad idea because it lets you put the Matrix in an inconsistent state, where Python believes it's bigger than the storage allocated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! would you elaborate what do you mean by **you allow assignment to the rows and columns properties. This is a bad idea because it lets you put the Matrix in an inconsistent state, where Python believes it's bigger than the storage allocated**

Comment: For example `getVal` and `setVal` use the result of `self._columns` to decide which element to pick. However, the `columns` property has a setter, so a user could assign `self._columns` to any value. It just seems like something they shouldn't be able to change when there's methods for adding rows and columns properly.

Comment: Thanks again for the useful answer. Can I ask another question, more and less related to this one?

Comment: I was trying to implement **scaling** of the parameters of the matrix using `transform`, `bind1st` and `multiplies` by writing these lines:`cdef extern from "<functional>" namespace "std" nogil:
     cdef cppclass multiplies[T]:
          multiplies()
     cdef cppclass bind1st[Fun,T]:
         binder1st<multiplies<double>>bind1st(multiplies[double], double)
`and `transform(self.matrix.begin( ), self.matrix.end(), self.matrix.begin( ), bind1st(multiplies[double](),c))` but I guess I did not wrap `bind1st` correctly. Would you please give a hint how it should be done?

Comment: Cython isn't really very good at templates and this looks complicated. I'd be tempted to write this code in C++ - create a C++ function `multiply_by_constant(std::vector<double> v, double c)` and then wrap that with Cython instead. I don't think I can make this work in Cython alone.

Comment: I guess `unary_function` struct,  `binder1st` class and `bind1st` should be wrapped in order to use `bind1st` and then [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77546/multiply-vector-elements-by-a-scalar-value-using-stl-and-templates). I am not very familiar how  to wrap classes and templates in cython so I am struggling to find out how it should be done.

Comment: something similar to [this](https://github.com/molpopgen/cython_cpp_iterators/blob/85b50e215d55f5380859027ea228edb20e2e6069/iterator_test/iterator.pyx) just for using `copy` for vectors: `cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std" nogil:    
     OutputIter copy[InputIter,OutputIter](InputIter,InputIter,OutputIter)`